# Positive numbers and functions satisfying some conditions

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to show that there are positive numbers p and q, and unique functions u and v mapping from interval $(-1-p,-1+p)$ to $(1-q,1+q)$ such that
$$xe^{u(x)}+u(x)e^{v(x)}=0=xe^{v(x)}+v(x)e^{u(x)}$$
for all x in the interval $(-1-p,-1+p)$ with $u(-1)=v(-1)=1$ 
I am clueless as to where to start solving this question

Answer (score 0):

1) First note that $u(x)=v(x)=-x$ is a solution.

2) Now I take $p=q$ and $0<p<1/2$. Note that we have $xu(x)v(x)\not =0$ for all $x$ if $(u,v)$ is a solution.

3)From your equations we get $\displaystyle \exp(v(x))=-\frac{x}{u(x)}\exp(u(x))$ and $v(x)\exp(-v(x))=-x\exp(-u(x))$. Multiplying, we have $u(x)v(x)=x^2$.

4) Your system is hence equivalent to i) $u(x)v(x)=x^2$ and ii) $\displaystyle  \exp(x^2/u(x)-u(x)=-x/u(x)$.

5) Fix $x_0\in (-1-p,-1+p)$. Put $F(y)=y\exp(x_0^2/y-y)$. The derivative of $F$ is $\displaystyle -\frac{y^2-y+x_0^2}{y}\exp(x_0^2/y-y)$.
The polynomial $y^2-y+x_0^2$ has its discriminant $\Delta=1-4x_0^2$. With the hypothesis on $p$, $\Delta<0$. Hence $F^{\prime}$ is strictly negative on $]0,+\infty[$, and the equation $F(y)=-x_0$ has only a solution, namely $y=-x_0$. This show that ii) imply that $u(x)=-x$ for all $x$, and by i), $v(x)=-x$.